# Getting the following error Illuminate\Database\QueryException could not find driver (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `snippets`)

Tags: laravel

Hello I am getting the following error in laravel 6

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException
could not find driver (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `snippets`)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu You must validate if the version of the php that it uses is the same one that has the drivers.
Example:

1. create info.php file inside public / info.php
2. look at the php version
3. install mysql extensions for that version, for version 7.2 this should be
   `sudo apt-get install php7.2-mysql`